# Escaping Variable in Cat

Tags: ssh, php, environment-variables, cat

I'm trying to write a shell script over ssh via a bash prompt. The shell, however, insists on interpreting any variable I want to write instead of writing it directly to file. For example, `cat <<EOF >checkup.sh\n'$command'EOF` is simply written as `''` to file. How do I get `$command` written instead? I've tried every practical method of escaping I can think of.

If it changes anything, I'm doing it over PHP using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try quoting the first `EOF`, e.g.,

```
cat <<'EOF'
>checkup.sh\n'$command'
EOF
```

This is explained in the bash(1) man page, in the section, Here Documents.

Comment: I actually needed the INVERSE of this (had a script with "EOF", needed to handle variables) and this pointed me at it. 

Thanks!